# Assign a negative sign to every value in a vector (in R)?

Tags: r, assign

I want this:

```
V <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
V <- as.data.frame(V)
```

To look like this:

```
[1] -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

Essentially the reverse of the abs() function. Thanks.

Comment: just do `V <- -V`

Comment: or `*-1` etc. i felt that this was probably a dupe but I actually don't see another one exactly like this.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a duplicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know beforehand whether all values of the vector are positive, then you should do something like the code below.

```
V <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
W <- c(-2, -3, -4, -5, -6)
X <- c(2, -3, 4, -5, 6)

all.neg <- function(x) -1*abs(x)
```

Let's try it.

```
all.neg(V)
#[1] -2 -3 -4 -5 -6

all.neg(W)
#[1] -2 -3 -4 -5 -6

all.neg(X)
#[1] -2 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

If you want to apply it to a data.frame, then do it the usual way.

```
dat <- data.frame(V, W, X)

dat[] <- lapply(dat, all.neg)
dat
#   V  W  X
#1 -2 -2 -2
#2 -3 -3 -3
#3 -4 -4 -4
#4 -5 -5 -5
#5 -6 -6 -6
```

Comment: `dat[] <- -abs(as.matrix(dat))`

Comment: @jogo Or `dat <- all.neg(dat)` without the `[]` since `class(all.neg(dat))` returns `[1] "data.frame"`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
 V * -1
```

or

```
-V # first mentioned in the comments by @RHertel
```

or anything like that. With assignment (updating the object) it looks like this:

```
v <- v * -1 # or -V
```

You can also use `=` for assignment but it goes against the style guides.

> [1] -2 -3 -4 -5 -6